# TODO tasks not displaying in the task view in eclipse 2019-09 with latest version of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse

I am writing a simple node.js project using latest version of  eclipse 
Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
OS: Mac OS X, v.10.15.1, x86_64 / cocoa
Java version: 12.0.2
using latest version of node.js (Node.js v12.13.0)
I have the TODO tasks are not appearing in the task view window: the sample code is

```
/**
 * http://sample/
 */
//TODO I will start coding from here
console.log("this is it ");
```

The task in the comment is not appearing in the task view of eclipse. I have tried to follow all answers nothing could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to report this as an enhancement request at https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues . That package uses a newer, experimental, set of JavaScript support.